# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.generative'

Tags: python, pip, modulenotfounderror, python-3.10, google-generativeai

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\CHANDRA SHEKHAR\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 535, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)

File "D:\mlproject\app.py", line 9, in <module>
    import google.generative as genai
```

This error is shown. For `generativeai`, I tried all methods to install by typing command `pip install google-generativeai` in `cmd`, but still `generativea ai` is not coming in generativea.

I am trying this on Python 3.10 version.

Tried to install the library by giving command `pip install google-generativeai` still no results.

Answer (score 3):

To install from PyPI, run `pip install google-generativeai`. [Obtain an API key from AI Studio](https://makersuite.google.com/app/apikey), then configure it here.

**Also, your import statement is wrong**. You did `import google.generative as genai` but it should be `import google.generativeai as genai`. See [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/google-generativeai/).